# React - Identify an element render (paint) completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In angular, we can write a directive to identify whether any element is rendered or not.

In react, we can use `*useEffect*` for the component mount.
But in reality, the element is not available in the dom. How to identify whether the dom completes the render. I need to calculate the position and height of an element. But cannot identify the render completes. Always gets zero for the height.

In a component, I am looping an element.

For example,

```
array.map(item=> <div>Show data</div>)
```

In this above, I want to do some action when the **show data** has been displayed in the dom.
If we have 10k records of `<div>Show data</div>`, then I need to wait for those elements to render completely then need to do some actions for them. But only after completion.

Comment: useEffect is only ever called after the first render, though conditionally rendered elements may not be available. Use ref if you want a reference to an element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out useLayoutEffect hook to access the DOM after rendering: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const { height } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  setTooltipHeight(height);
}, []);
```

Comment: It is just after rendering before painting, but useEffect is after painting so if the OP has problems with useEffect useLayoutEffect won't help

Answer (score 0):

you can use useRef to get html element when it will be rendered in DOM, after first render you can get width/height (elementRef.current?.offsetHeight).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, using a `ref`:

```
const [divHeight, setDivHeight] = useState(0);

const handleRect = useCallback(node => {
  if (node !== null) {
    setDivHeight(Math.round(node.getBoundingClientRect().height));
  }
}, []);


// ...

return (
  <div ref={handleRect}>
    .....   
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't ask about to set the height. I have asked about after completes the render, I need to get/identify the height of an element.

Comment: My actual aim is to identify the element render completion

Comment: This is only setting the height as state, so you can use it anywhere else. See this interactive example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-lqwm41?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: I don't want to set height. I could understand your answer. Thanks for your effort. The state will apply the height whenever the element is rendered. But my purpose is vice versa. I need to know when the element is rendered. My purpose is not to set the height.

Comment: This does not set the height, it get's it after the component is rendered and stores in in some state so you can use it elsewhere. In the example above I simply print it so you can see what the height is. Try adding more content to the div and see it only gets the height.